# Create a file object of zip file based on a blob for formdata in a fetch

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, fetch-api

I would like to upload a zip file as part of formdata in a Javascript fetch.
I can easily send in a zip file which I have read in via a file input control (see first segment of code). But when  try to create a file object based on a blob, I receive an error (see second segment of code).

Basically I am asking how to create a zip file object from a blob. I tried many variations of code, but cannot nail the right syntax of creating the file object from blob, but it has to be a zip file. Note that the zip file is a shapefile - not sure if it makes any difference.

```
  //here we upload the zip file 
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('avatar');   
  var filename = fileInput.files[0].name;

  //This works fine. I can easily send the zip file in formdata
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.set('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.set("time", false) 
  formData.set("base_file", fileInput.files[0] )

  fetch("/upload/", {
     "credentials": "include",
     "body": formData,
     "headers": headers,
     "method": "POST",
     "mode": "cors"
     })
```

But when I try to upload zip file I created from a blob, then I receive an error

```
  var shpBuffer = await ShapeFileFromGeoJSON(geojson, fileName); 
  var base64String = Uint8Array.from(window.atob(shpBuffer), (v) => v.charCodeAt(0));
  var shapeFileBlob = new Blob([ base64String ], {type:"application/zip"});
  saveAs(shapeFileBlob, fileName);  //this works and a zip file is saved


  var file = new File([shapeFileBlob], 'application.zip', { type: shapeFileBlob.type,});
  console.log(file);
  //Returns: "File {name: 'application.zip', lastModified: 1656002582746, 
  //lastModifiedDate: Fri Jun 24 2022 04:43:02 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time), 
  //webkitRelativePath: '', size: 6091726, …}"
  console.log(file instanceof File);  //returns true

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.set('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.set("time", false) 
  formData.set("file", file) 

  fetch("/upload/", {
     "credentials": "include",
     "body": formData,
     "headers": headers,
     "method": "POST",
     "mode": "cors"
     })
```

The error returned in the console is

```
POST https://WEBSITE/upload/ 400 (Bad Request)
   {success: false, errors: Array(1)}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't know - what does the server complain about? Did you look into its logs? Are you sure this is a valid zip file?

Comment: @Bergi I have just checked the server logs. No entry for this error is made there.
So probably it is a Javascript error thrown in by browser for the file format. The request does not even reach the server.
I am sure the error lies in this line of code:  
**var shapeFileBlob = new Blob([ base64String ], {type:"application/zip"})**

Comment: I don't think so, it very much looks like a json response. What is `errors: Array(1)`?

Comment: `{success: false, errors: Array(1)}
errors: Array(1)
0: "Unexpected exception string index out of range"
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
success: false
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: Added picture of error message in main post.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that error message is coming from your backend. Please check that your logging is in order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245902/discussion-between-paul-butler-and-bergi).

Comment: Please show the serverside code that is processing this. For now, the difference between your codes, according to the log output, is that one has `type: "application/x-zip-compressed"` and the other doesn't, also they have different contents obviously.

Comment: That said, `base64String = Uint8Array.from(window.atob(shpBuffer), (v) => v.charCodeAt(0))` looks really sketchy. What does `ShapeFileFromGeoJSON` do? Why do you expect this code to produce a valid zip archive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think I solved the question. The issue was in the way I was creating the zip file - which is a shapefile. The shapefile zip file should unzip into the files directly without into any intermediate folder. Geoserver was rejecting it as upon unzipping it could not directly find any shapefile.